# Why does NSLog print an extra zero when logging this array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

With these variables:

```
NSInteger dataStart;
uint64_t dataSize[1];
const unsigned char *beginning;
NSInteger bytesEnd;
```

...at these values:

```
dataStart = 499
dataSize[0] = 427
beginning = 9060864
bytesEnd = 9061793
```

...the following code:

```
NSLog(@"dataStart = %d, dataSize[0] = %d, beginning = %d, bytesEnd = %d",
        dataStart, dataSize[0], (NSInteger)beginning, bytesEnd);
```

...sends this to the console:

```
dataStart = 499, dataSize[0] = 427, beginning = 0, bytesEnd = 9060864
```

In other words, an extra zero has been inserted after the array, bumping the other variables along. It does this consistently. I'm using xcode 3.2.3. What is happening here?

[Edit for emphasis: It's not just the old favorite of printing a zero where a value should be because a cast is wrong. It's inserting an extra zero, then printing the correct value of beginning where it should print bytesEnd, and not printing bytesEnd.]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but are you compiling in 64-bit mode? The beginning pointer is 64 bits in that case, but NSInteger is 32-bits, so you're only printing the high-order 32-bit bits of the pointer which are zero.

I guess this is a contrived example because no one in their right mind would cast like this. Right?

Comment: It's not just printing zero instead of a value, it's adding an extra value and moving the other variables along one. That's the weird thing. I did the mouseover in the debugger to make sure that's what the values were.

"No one in their right mind" would be Jeff LaMarche & David Mark :-) (I'm trying to get their splitTransferredPackets method in chapter 9 of More iPhone 3 Development working for decent amounts of data).

Comment: Of course it's moving the other variables along: NSLog assumes that the value is 32 bits, but it is 64-bits, so it also occupies the address for the next value. If you're compiling in 64-bits mode, you shouldn't cast a pointer to NSInteger anyway.

Comment: I haven't told it to compile in 64-bit mode, & I'm programming for iPhone so I don't think it would be. Also it's logging it elsewhere fine. But this explanation makes sense for dataSize[0] occupying 2 addresses as it is indeed a 64 bit integer, so have a tick and an upvote :-)

Comment: -1 The answer is incorrect.  Jeff Laing's answer below is almost right but wrong in 32 bit mode.  datasize[0] is 64 bits wide and takes 64 bits on the stack, but with the %d you are telling NSLog it is only 32 bits wide.    By the way, in 64 bit mode, NSInteger is 64 bits, so the %d is wrong for NSIntegers too.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong format selector.  %d is not sufficient to print a uint64_t which is what datasize[0] is.  Use %ld.